# Vector relationships

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

I'm a beginner with vector calculus and analysis and I am looking at the following example problem. Please note that is is not a homework question, I am simply looking at some vector relationships. The problem is asking to show for any vector ${\overrightarrow{\mathbf{F}}}$

$$({\overrightarrow{\mathbf{F}}}\cdot{{\overrightarrow{\mathbf{\nabla}}}}){\overrightarrow{\mathbf{r}}}={\overrightarrow{\mathbf{F}}}$$

It is asking to show this in cartesian coordinates. I was wondering what the starting point is for such an example. I have looked quite intesively on the world wide web, as you'd expect, and can't seem to find a specific example which I could use to start this proof.

Comment: an obvious solution for $\stackrel{\to}{r}$ is the identity map $1\!\!1(x^1,...,x^n)=(x^1,...,x^n)$

Comment: I don't particularly want to use suffix notation, I just want to specify some vector F and then battle through with the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Denote
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{r}=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})
\end{equation*}
Now

\begin{eqnarray*}
(\mathbf{F\cdot \nabla )r} &=&\mathbf{F} \\
(\sum_{l=1}^{3}F_{l}\frac{\partial }{\partial _{x_{l}}})x_{k} &=&F_{k}
\end{eqnarray*}
But
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial }{\partial _{x_{l}}}x_{k}=\delta _{kl}
\end{equation*}
so the left hand side equals the right hand side

Comment: It would probably be best to not use this suffix notation but rather something akin to an undergraduate level proof.